How to sum values until a certain text value is reached
Below is a sample of my data

This is data from a pipe model I created. I am trying to create an excel formula that returns the lengths between bend points (i.e. summing all lengths of "run" until the next instance of "bend occurs"). What makes it somewhat tricky is that each bend point has a near (N) and far (F) node in the output data. So each output value will have to be repeated twice. I have also included a sample of my current output data, and I believe that the values for "distance between bends" is correct but I have done this manually so I would like to be able to automate and verify the process. Thank you

Current set up is manually using SUM functions and selecting the data myself. I tried to use chatgpt to provide a formula but it returned this which is incorrect.
=IF(A2 = "Bend", "", C2 - INDEX(C:C, MATCH("Bend", A:A, 0)))

I also tried to use variations of SUMIF functions but I couldn't get it right. Could some form of SUMIF and XLOOKUP be used?
EDIT:
@cybernetic.nomand thank you so much for your help. That formula has worked and has verified all of my answers. I have posted the result of my output data, I have pasted your formula in column K. As you can see the values are correct I just need to find a way to get rid of the blank cells, as well as repeat each value twice.


Try: =IF(A2="BEND",SUM(C$1:C2)-SUM(F$1:F1),"") (this assumes the formulas are in column F

Hi, thanks for your quick reply but unfortunately that doesn't work. In the first pic, the sample of my input data, the data starts at column A and ends at column E. From the input data, I am trying to sum the values in column E until "bend" is reached in column D.
In the output data, I will be planning to put the formula into the third column, "distance from previous bend", which is column C.
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Put =IF(D2="BEND",SUM(E$1:E2)-SUM(F$1:F1),"") in column F of the first table

Hey, thank you so much, that formula has worked! I have edited my question so that I could upload a picture and request your help with two final changes.

Us the formula in the first table, then a VLOOKUP to find the value matching the first column somehting like (=VLOOKUP(J2,A$2:F$20,6) Where J2 has one of the bend ID (ex.: U02) and A2:F20 is the first table
